# C: Representation of Big Integers

Tags: c

So, let's say I've created a struct of 3 32-bit integers that act as a 96-bit integer.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int x, y, z;
} Int96;
```

Let's take this to mean that int x is the first integer to be filled. Before it overflows, y is incremented and x is refreshed back to 0. z functions similarly, but takes care of y's overflow.

How would I go about printing the value stored in this struct? Surely I can't directly print out the full value without causing an overflow on my system.

Comment: Carefully — does that count as an answer? Hex is easy; octal and decimal are harder.

Comment: No, you'd need to manually implement the add, subtract, etc. and conversion to strings yourself. You'd need to implement such that they work correctly with your data.

Comment: You probably won't like this answer, but the easiest way (that doesn't involve using another library) is to first implement division and modulus by 10. (assuming you want to print it out in base 10)

Comment: @Mysticial: Right. Once you've implemented arithmetic, you can use that to implement an integer-to-string conversion function.

Comment: If you can afford using a library, then I suggest [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) as way to go. It has support for all things listed here and much more (and documentation is very clear). Essentionally in C you have to program all basic operations by yourself.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yep. Which is why implementing bignums are very annoying. It's hard to do anything without being able to see it (print it). And you can't print it unless you have non-trivial functionality (division/modulus). That said, there are other ways to print it, but they're not trivial either. So you have to print it out in hex and use an external hex->decimal converter until you have enough functionality to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: Note: suggest naming it `UInt96`.

Comment: "int x is the first integer to be filled" -- you can slightly make it easier by *not* filling your integers up to full capacity, but only up to the largest factor of 10. (Which for a 32-bit unsigned int would be 10⁹; you'd only *not* be using 2-and-a-bit bits.)

Comment: Better use a real bignum library like [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/). Notice that good algorithms for bignum are hard to understand or to reinvent.

Answer (score 4):

The first step is writing general purpose arithmetic routines for your `Int96`:

```
void Add96(Int96 *a, const Int96 *b) {
    // add b to a
    a->x += b->x;
    a->y += b->y;
    a->z += b->z;
    if (a->y < b->y) a->z++;
    if (a->x < b->x && ++a->y == 0) a->z++; }
void Sub96(Int96 *a, const Int96 *b);
void Mul96(Int96 *a, const Int96 *b);
void Div96(Int96 *a, const Int96 *b);
void Mod96(Int96 *a, const Int96 *b);
```

With those you can write:

```
void print96(const Int96 *val) {
    Int96 ten = { 10, 0, 0 };
    Int96 div = *val;
    Int96 mod = *val;
    Div96(&div, &ten);
    Mod96(&mod, &ten);
    if (div.x || div.y || div.z) print96(&div);
    putchar('0' + mod.x); }
```

You can make this more efficient by writing a `DivMod96uint` function that does the div and mod in a single step and takes an `unsigned` (rather than an `Int96`) for the second argument and returns the mod.  You can also avoid an extra copy per digit by having a `print96destructive` function that overwrites its argument, and have `print96` just make a copy and then call that:

```
void print96destructive(Int96 *val) {
    unsigned mod = DivMod96ui(val, 10);
    if (val->x || val->y || val->z) print96destructive(val);
    putchar('0' + mod); }
void print96(const Int96 *val) {
    Int96 v = *val;
    print96destructive(&v); }

unsigned DivMod96ui(Int96 *a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned mod = a->z % b;
    a->z /= b;
    uint64_t y = a->y + ((uint64_t)mod << 32);
    mod = y % b;
    a->y = y / b;
    uint64_t x = a->x + ((uint64_t)mod << 32);
    mod = x % b;
    a->x = x / b;
    return mod; }
```

Comment: +1 for the nifty `if (a->x < b->x && ++a->y == 0) a->z++; }` and `if (div.x || div.y || div.z) print96(&div);`.